# is it possible to implement dynamic polymorphism using interface in C#.net

Tags: c#, dynamic, polymorphism

is it possible to implement dynamic polymorphism using interface in C#.net.  Dynamic polymorphism can be done only by using abstract class ?

Answer (score 1):

In the interface you cannot specify the accessibility of the functions, while in the abstract classes you specify exactly what your functions are and you can only override them. If you can use interfaces to solve your problem you don't need to implement dynamic polymorphism. You can read more about what I'm talking here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx